# How to do FTP Server (ingest) load balancing in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, load-balancing, amazon-elb, google-cloud-load-balancer

How to do load balancing of a FTP server running in a VM with different users? The FTP server is a passive one that only have ingest, how to make it autoscale if I add more users dynmaically?  Is it specific to the server I chose, currently I'm using python-ftp server and in it's documentation saying that it can support 300max users? Elastic Load Balancing for FTP in AWS dooesn't support?
If it is possible what are the ports should I allow in ELC in GCP?
Or should I naively go for increasing capability of my VM?
Thanks!!

Eleastic load balancing ports support in GCP

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use (install) an FTP server that supports load balancing. Google Cloud does not offer an FTP server service or software product.